# Python Shell script not called in Symfony

Tags: php, python, laravel, symfony, laravel-5

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and I have implemented openFace library which works fine through terminal that takes two input parameter containing name of images

**Terminal command**

```
python /home/machine/openface/demos/compare_two_pic.py {/home/machine/openface/demos/images/5G5X0dnI5xkD.jpg,/home/machine/openface/demos/images/orange.jpg}
```

I just pasted this command in Symfony but i didn't get any result.

```
$process = new Process(['python2', '/home/machine/openface/demos/compare_two_pic.py {/home/machine/openface/demos/images/5G5X0dnI5xkD.jpg,/home/machine/openface/demos/images/orange.jpg}',$arg(optional)]);

        $process->run();
echo "here".$process->getOutput();

// executes after the command finishes
        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
        }

        echo $process->getOutput();
```

I make a web service to just call a function and check. Is this function working or not?
[image: The output of function]

I have put this comment

```
$process = Process::fromShellCommandline('python2 /home/machine/openface/demos/compare_two_pic.py {/home/machine/openface/demos/images/5G5X0dnI5xkD.jpg,/home/machine/openface/demos/images/orange.jpg}');
```

[image]

Comment: its clearly telling you that $arg(optional) isnt defined. Is it?

Comment: How can i define it?

Comment: It depends on what you would want the script to do, it seems like this was meant to be an arg to the script. Dont pass it if you dont know what it is, if you do know the intended arg then do something like this new Process(['python', 'script.py', 'arg1', 'arg2']), more here https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

Comment: The problem is different